# Why Motorola 68k's 32-bit general-purpose registers are divided into data registers and address registers?

Tags: motorola, 68000

The 68k registers are divided into two groups of eight. Eight data registers (D0 to D7) and eight address registers (A0 to A7). What is the purpose of this separation, would not be better if united?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, this separation comes from the architecture limitations and design decisions made at the time.

The long answer:

The M68K implements quite a lot of *addressing modes* (especially when compared with the RISC-based processors), with many of its instructions supporting most (if not all) of them. This gives a large variety of addressing modes combinations within every instruction.

This also adds a complexity in terms of opcode execution. Take the following example:

```
move.l $10(pc), -$20(a0,d0.l)
```

The instruction is just to copy a long-word from one location to another, simple enough. But in order to actually perform the operation, the processor needs to figure out the actual (raw) memory addresses to work with for both source and destination operands. This process, in which operands addressing modes are decoded (resolved), is called the *effective address calculation*.

For this example:

1. In order to calculate the source effective address - **$10(pc)**,
   the processor loads the value of **PC** (program) counter register
   and adds **$10** to it.
2. In order to calculate the destination effective address -
       **-$20(a0,d0.l)**, the processor loads the value of **A0** register, adds the value of **D0** register to it, then subtracts
   **$20**.

This is quite a lot of calculations of a single opcode, isn't it?

But the M68K is quite fast in performing these calculations. In order to calculate effective addresses quickly, it implements a dedicated ***Address Unit*** (AU).

As a general rule, operations on data registers are handled by the **ALU** (Arithmetic Logical Unit) and operations involving address calculations are handled by the **AU** (Address Unit).

The AU is well optimized for 32-bit address operations: it performs 32-bit subtraction/addition within one bus cycle (4 CPU ticks), which ALU doesn't (it takes 2 bus cycles for 32-bit operations).

However, the **AU** is limited to just load and basic addition/subtraction operations (as dictated by the addressing modes), and it's not connected to the **CCR** (Conditional Codes Register), which is why operations on address registers never update flags.

That said, the **AU** should've been there to optimize calculation of complex addressing modes, but it just couldn't replace the **ALU** completely (after all, there were only about 68K transistors in the M68K), hence there are two registers set (data and address registers) each having their own dedicated unit.

Answer (score 0):

So this is just based on a quick lookup, but using 16 registers is obviously easier to program. The problem could be that you would then have to make instructions for each of the 16 registers. Which would double the number of opcodes needed. Using half for each purpose is not ideal but gives access to more registers in general.

Comment: could explain more? I am interested in this topic